# Infinispan Memcached(text-based) protocol and Hotrod(binary) protocol

Tags: memcached, protocols, infinispan

We are simulating infinispan in various situations:

1. client and server nodes running on same host
2. client and server nodes running on different hosts in same location
3. client and server nodes running on different hosts in different locations

here are the results we observed:

1. hotrod timing are far better than memcached timings.
2. hotrod timing are better than memcached timings, even after the fact hotrod timing increased a bit because of i think network transmission and all
   BUT, in case:
3. when communication is happening between our internal nyc and hyd host, hotrod timing are way larger then expected and memcached timings can be considered far better than hotRod

We are not able to guess any valid reason for this. Any help will be appreciated.

I have also posted my question [here](https://community.jboss.org/message/850329) with our simulation results. Please check.

Thanks,
Sonal

Comment: This is so wide topic, that anyone will need much, much more information about your settings, network, configurations, scenarios, testing tools, framework...

Comment: Actually we are trying very simple simulation with default configuration of infinispan memcache protocol (text) and infinispan Hot Rod protocol(binary), we have put few objects of different size in caching sever and tried reading using clients, In our first simulation we have run client and server both on same host and in another simulation we have run client and server on different host... In both of the cases Hot Rod outperformed memcache...

Comment: but surprising part was that difference in read timing was not much in case of memcache in both simulations... but in case of Hot Rod it was significant...In fact on running same simulation on different host (where ping time for packet size 32 is around 200ms) difference was very low (1sec) in case of memcache for object of size 30 MB but in case of hot rod it was really huge(30sec).. I just want to understand how come in case of memcache network transmission time is so less ... you can assume our network speed is 1000 Mbps..

Comment: If you use big objects (30 MB), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20722620/how-to-set-send-buffer-size-and-receive-buffer-size-in-infinispan-hotrod-client might be of relevance.